# The planner endpoints to get tasks is returning a 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I use the graph explorer 1.0 to test out the planner endpoints i'm getting a 404. I therefore cannot get the task id to parse into the other endpoints

I have tried the following 2 endpoints

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[useremail]/planner/tasks

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks

I've authenticated in the graph explorer.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: i'm using a personal microsoft account - i wonder if that's the reason and the following documentation states it's not supported - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Planner API for personal accounts currently. That is why you are getting a 404.

Comment: i was using a personal account. Sounds like that was the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All right to your account. It does not work with a personal account. I am not sure if you are using these endpoints through application permission that won't work either. The first endpoint has two //, that could be the issue also. I tried both endpoints and it works for me, so definitely some permission or type of account issues on your end.

Comment: i was using a personal account. Sounds like that was the issue. thanks